# Unexpected token ')' Nodejs with Couchdb

Tags: node.js, database, express, nosql, couchdb

I  am using nodejs 14 and couchdb database 3.1.1
I am trying to connect and display list of couchdb databases using nodejs but following error occur

```
   const NodeCouchDb = require('node-couchdb');`
 
 
    const couch = new NodeCouchDb();
 
    // node-couchdb instance with Memcached
    const MemcacheNode = require('node-couchdb-plugin-memcached');
    const couchWithMemcache = new NodeCouchDb({
      cache: new MemcacheNode
   });
 
    // node-couchdb instance talking to external service
     const couchExternal = new NodeCouchDb({
     host: 'couchdb.external.service',
     protocol: 'https',
     port: 5984
    });
 
    // not admin party
    const couchAuth = new NodeCouchDb({
        auth: {
           user: 'admin',
          pass: 'godhelp'
       }
    });

      couch.listDatabases()
        .then(
           dbs => dbs.map(...), 
            err => {
           // request error occured 
      });
```

ERROR After Compiled  :

```
        dbs => dbs.map(...), 
                     ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a syntax error in your code, but more fundamentally `node-couchdb` seems to be an inactive library that has not been updated in more than four years. I would recommend using [nano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano), which is the official Apache CouchDB NodeJS library.

Here's a simple NodeJS script (`index.js`) using nano to list your databases.

```
const nano = require('nano')(process.env.COUCH_URL)

const main = async function() {
  const response = await nano.db.list()
  console.log(response)
}

main ()
```

You will need to create an environment variable called COUCH_URL:

```
export COUCH_URL="http://user:password@localhost:5984"
```

and then run the script:

```
node index.js
#[ 'deeds' ]
```